# In spray how to unmarshall plain/text?

Tags: scala, spray

Can anybody show me an example in spray how to unmarshall POST with content type plain/text ?

How to write the route?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how the route would look like:

```
  post {
    entity(as[String]) { str =>
      complete(str)
    }
  }
```

A sample request would be:

```
curl -X POST -d 'It works' localhost:8080
```

which echoes back the POST data.

To get the whole sample app use this official [template](https://github.com/spray/spray-template) and add/edit the route.

If you want to understand how it works in detail see [this doc](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-routing/marshalling-directives/entity/) and [this](http://spray.io/documentation/1.2.2/spray-httpx/unmarshalling/#unmarshalling) one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried this piece of code together with https://github.com/mhamrah/spray-sample, and I got the message "Expected 'application/json'", it seems that some setting need be done. Can you kindly explain to me? Thanks so much!

Comment: HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
* Server spray-can/1.3.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: spray-can/1.3.1
< Date: Sat, 22 Nov 2014 21:07:51 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 79
< 
There was a problem with the requests Content-Type:
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
Expected 'application/json'

Comment: please try this in a service without JSON support, i.e. not in that project. It seems that JSON unmarshaller takes over all conversions and sets the expected media type to json. I'll try to give a better explanation soon when I find some time ;). Here is a good template to start with: https://github.com/spray/spray-template

Comment: Yes, you need to be careful with importing `SprayJsonSupport._` etc. Optimally, you just import it exactly in the scopes where you need it and not globally for the file which contains all of your routes.

Comment: Any idea why in akka http string implicit is not always available? see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/p-m1eKm3-YM