# How to unmarshall akka http request entity as string?

Tags: json, scala, akka-http

I'm trying to unmarshall request payload as string, but for some reason it's failing. My code:

```
path("mypath") {

  post {
    decodeRequest {
      entity(as[String]) {jsonStr => //could not find implicit value for...FromRequestUnmarshaller[String]
        complete {
          val json: JsObject = Json.parse(jsonStr).as[JsObject]
          val jsObjectFuture: Future[JsObject] = MyDatabase.addListItem(json)
          jsObjectFuture.map(_.as[String])
        }
      }          
    }
  }
}
```

In this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27073173/in-spray-how-to-unmarshall-plain-text) for example it seems to be that this implicit should be available by default. But maybe this is different in akka-http?

I tried importing `akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.PredefinedFromEntityUnmarshallers` which has a `stringUnmarshaller` but it doesn't help. Maybe because this returns type `FromEntityUnmarshaller[String]` not `FromRequestUnmarshaller[String]`. There's also a string unmarshaller in `spray.httpx.unmarshalling.BasicUnmarshallers` but this also doesn't help, neither `akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.PredefinedFromStringUnmarshallers`

How can I unmarshall (and marshall) into a string?

(Bonus: How to unmarshall directly in a JsObject (play json). But also only string as I'm interested in why this is not working and it may be useful for other cases).

Using 1.0-RC3

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your code should be okay provided you have the right implicits in scope.  If you have an implicit `FlowMaterializer` in scope then things should work as expected as this code that compiles shows:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorFlowMaterializer
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.StatusCodes._
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.stream.FlowMaterializer

implicit val system = ActorSystem("test")
implicit val mater = ActorFlowMaterializer()

val routes:Route = {
  post{
    decodeRequest{
      entity(as[String]){ str =>
        complete(OK, str) 
      }
    }
  }    
}
```

If you wanted to take things a step further and unmarshall to a `JsObject` then you just need an implicit `Unmarshaller` in scope to handle that conversion, something like this:

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem("test")
implicit val mater = ActorFlowMaterializer()

import akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.Unmarshaller
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpEntity

implicit val um:Unmarshaller[HttpEntity, JsObject] = {
  Unmarshaller.byteStringUnmarshaller.mapWithCharset { (data, charset) =>
    Json.parse(data.toArray).as[JsObject]
  }    
}  

val routes:Route = {
  post{
    decodeRequest{
      entity(as[String]){ str =>
        complete(OK, str) 
      }
    }
  } ~
  (post & path("/foo/baz") & entity(as[JsObject])){ baz =>
    complete(OK, baz.toString)
  }    
}
```

Comment: Thanks! My problem was that I declared the ActorFlowMaterializer implicit below the routes definition... it's quite hard to spot that this is the reason for the marshalling part not compiling, for a newbie like me just impossible...

Comment: Besides of that I must have missed that order is important when declaring implicits, or something else, because the variables were in scope - just below routes.

Comment: Thanks also for the json unmarshaller, I'm actually using string, not byteString (this was just a test), but could adjust it easily to work with string.